# rails list records attribute like x

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For instance I have 4 bill records.

```
id    = 1 
prize = 100
city  = "newyork"

id    = 2
prize = 200
city  = "NEWYORK"

id    = 3 
prize = 300
city  = "Boston"

id    = 4
prize = 400
city  = "BOSTON"
```

I want to get statistics of cities with hash like `{"Newyork" => 2 , "Boston" => 2 }`

Answer (score 0):

```
your_collection.group_by(&:city)
```